# Find the number of transactions happening per minute

Tags: mysql, count, timestamp

I have a table that has timestamp, and counters. I want to find the number of counters that take place per minute.

This is the table that I have
[image]

I want the output to be

```
2  2021-07-23 15:50
0  2021-07-23 15:49
15 2021-07-23 15:48
```

I looked at other solutions on stack overflow but some of them were so old that the syntax is no longer valid. Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created your table and ran the following query to make sure it is correct

go ahead

```
SELECT 
COUNT(id), FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(t_stamp / 1000), '%Y-%M-%D %h:%i') 
FROM `for_group_by_timestamp` 
GROUP BY 
FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(t_stamp / 1000), '%Y-%M-%D %h:%i')
```

It's not optimal, but it does the job